# Can someone tell me why $\log_b(c) = s \cdot \log_b(d) \implies c = d$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I encountered this statement on the [U of T calculus preparation website, on the function and inverses section](http://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/4_functions/self-test.html).

Exercise 8 has two hints, the second of which states the following:

> If $\log_b(c) = s \cdot \log_b(d)$, then we can conclude that $c=d$ since logarithmic functions are one-to-one

But $\log_{10}(100) = 2 \cdot \log_{10}(10)$, and $100 \neq 10$.

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: This is true iff $s=1$.

Comment: The statement you quoted is not true in general. You can conclude $c=d^s$.

Comment: Guessing by hint 1 and its context, multiplying $s$ seems to be a typo. "$\log_b (c) = \log_b (d)$ implies $c = d$ because logarithmic functions are one-to-one." is natural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a typo and it is not true.

On [the web site](http://www.math.toronto.edu/preparing-for-calculus/4_functions/self-test.html) the problem is:

> The solution to $2\ln(x)+\ln(x+2)−\ln(x^2+2x)=−ln(2)$ is:

The first hint lists the three basic log identities:

1. $\log_b(r⋅s)=\log_br+\log_bs$
2. $\log_b(\frac rs)=\log_br−\log_bs$
3. $\log_b(r^s)=s\log_br$

Which you are to apply to $2\ln(x)+\ln(x+2)−\ln(x^2+2x)=−ln(2)$ to get

$\ln \frac {x^2(x+2)}{x+2} = \ln x = -\ln(2)$

$\ln x = -\ln 2$

Then the second hint was $ \log_b(c)=s⋅\log_b(d)\implies c = d$.  That had a typo.  They mean $ \log_b(c)=s\log_b(d)\implies c = d^s$

To which you are to apply $x = 2^{-1} = \frac 12$

Answer (score 2):

Your statement implies $c = d^s$ so the implication would only be true iff $s = 1.$ Also in general, a function $f$ is injective iff $f(x) = f(y)$ implies $x = y.$

Answer (score 1):

$$\log_b(c) = s \cdot \log_b(d)$$ does not imply $$c=d$$ unless $s=1$.

Thus you are correct in detecting the typo in the problem.